Restrictions on attachments in Google Chat
Question 1:
Is there any limit on the number or total file size of attachments in Google Chat within a single Google Workspace organization? Or is there no specific limit set by the service, and the policy is to increase backend infrastructure resources as the total volume grows? I understand that there are certain limits for Google Drive as mentioned in the following link:
https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/7338880?hl=en#membership
I would like to confirm if similar limits apply to Google Chat as well, considering the specified limits I recognize for Google Chat here:
https://developers.google.com/workspace/chat/limits?hl=en
Question 2:
Does the answer to Question 1 apply equally to the use of Google Chat from the interface and through the Media.Upload REST API, or are there different limits for each?
